# Nested Form Validation in AngularJS 1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I am currently working on child form validation with AngularJS v1.6.4 I have an 'A' directive called isolateForm in each child form.

My objective is that a child form's validation doesn't propagate to the parent form and vice versa.

In the following link has the code which can achieve the goal:
http://jsfiddle.net/gikoo/qNrFX/

However, in that example is running AngularJS v1.2.1. After updating to v1.6.4 the same code throws the following error:
http://jsfiddle.net/j3u1xed2/

```
 TypeError: ctrlCopy.$setValidity is not a function
        at Object.$setValidity (isolate-form.directive.js:40)
        at Object.clazz.$setValidity (angular.js:23502)
        at setValidity (angular.js:28716)
        at processParseErrors (angular.js:28655)
        at Object.$$runValidators (angular.js:28642)
        at ngModelWatch (angular.js:28962)
        at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17991)
        at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18269)
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26999)
        at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5201)
```

The problem is  `angular.copy(ctrl, ctrlCopy);` ctrlCopy doesn't copy the $setValidity function from the ctrl.

Is anybody knows how to solve this kind of  nested form validation problems in the new version of Angularjs? Or how to copy a $ function from one object to another.